# How can sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression still find a solution in the multi-collinear dataset？

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to train a LinearRegression model using the extended_boston dataset:

```py
from mglearn.datasets import load_extended_boston
X, y = load_extended_boston()

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linearReg = LinearRegression()
linearReg.fit(X, y)
```

For each of the features in `X`, the `LinearRegression` gives a corresponding coefficient.

However, X^TX is not **invertible**. For this reason, when I fit this linear model in `R`, the program will drop a feature automatically to find a solution.

Does sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression use some different algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Ridge regression` which is `LinearRegression` plus L2 regularization. L2 regularization means that it's not just minimizing the square distance to your objective but also tries to keep the coefficients small. This results in it being more stable with collinear datasets.

From the docs:

> Ridge regression addresses some of the problems of Ordinary Least
> Squares by imposing a penalty on the size of the coefficients. The
> ridge coefficients minimize a penalized residual sum of squares:
>
> The complexity parameter  controls the amount of shrinkage: the
> larger the value of , the greater the amount of shrinkage and thus the
> coefficients become more robust to collinearity.

See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ridge-regression
and
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html

I have to disagree with

> Antoine Dubuis: LinearRegression is using least square and therefore
> requires having an invertible X.T @ X.

Maybe it wasn't meant that way but it's not technically true that you have to have an invertible covariance matrix to do `linear regression/least squares`. E.g. you can do it using a QR decomposition. I guess he means that's necessary for the implementation in `scikit-learn`. But I think it is smart to do some kind of regularization. Think of it this way: If your issue is that there are many solutions to your problem (that's what this collinearity means) how do you wanna solve it? Do you wanna pick just any solution or do you wanna come up with a criterion that says which of the solutions is the best e.g. most regular?